# How to get variables from a url

Tags: python, django, paypal-rest-sdk

SO in using paypalrestsdk i have gone to paypal, submitted an order and the redirect url is:

> http://localhost:8000/confirm_order?paymentId=XYZ&token=123&PayerID=ABC

How do i dynamically obtain these values from the url??

Comment: Those are the `request.GET` parameters. `request.GET` is a `QueryDict` object that acts approximately like a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to pass data to a server. What you here describe are the [**`GET`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) parameters.

If you in a view inspect the `request.GET` object, you get a (possibly empty) [**`QueryDict`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) object. It acts more or less as a dictionary (except that a key can contain multiple values, etc.). For example:

```
def some_view(request):
    paymentId= request.GET['paymentId']
    token = request.GET['token']
    payerID = request.GET['PayerID']
    # do some processing
    # ...
    pass
```

Besides the `GET` parameters, there are other ways to transfer data between the client and server:

1. the URL itself (this can contain some data);
2. `request.POST` (those are parameters that are not encoded in the URL, but the header of the request);
3. `request.FILES` those contain ways to upload files;
4. `request.COOKIES` cookie data, send in the header, we can send cookies back to store some data during a session; and
5. `request.META` this contains headers in the request.

Comment: Strongly recommend usuing request.GET.get('paymentId') this avoid get server error 500

Comment: @DiegoVinícius: no, this is entirely against the Zen of Python: "*errors should never pass silently, unless sllenced explicitly*". In fact one of the projects I did was about changing all these kind of implicit solving, since it typically only results in more trouble in the end.

Comment: i mostly use get.get and run if to check if has values anyways... so i handle the possible errors

Comment: @DiegoVinícius: In that case I would use `try`-`except` instead. Since then it is perfectly clear what happens. By using `.get(..)` you *hide* this, and as a result, it will typically lead to a 500 somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this:

For **GET** request:

```
// ...inside you view function

if request.method == 'GET':
    // GET action
    paymentId = request.GET['paymentId']
    print('Payment ID:', paymentId)
    ...
```

For **POST** request:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    // POST action
    paymentId = request.POST['paymentId']
    print('Payment ID:', paymentId)
    ...
```

Comment: Well this is not entirely correct. even if the method is `POST`, then these are GET parameters. The GET ones are passed through the URL, the POST ones through the headers. A lot of POST requests, contain GET parameters...

Answer (score 0):

in this case, if there are no query parameters in the URL it will break,

**instead of this**

```
def some_view(request):
  paymentId= request.GET['paymentId']
  token = request.GET['token']
  payerID = request.GET['PayerID']
  # do some processing
  # ...
  pass
```

**try to change the code like this**

```
def some_view(request):
  paymentId= request.query_params.get('paymentId')
  token = request.query_params.get['token']
```

OR

```
  payerID = request.GET.get('PayerID')
  # do some processing
  # ...
  pass
```

In this case even if you do not send the query param, those variable contains None